# Getting error while adding Connected web service WCF reference into .Net Core API

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core

```
Importing web service metadata ...
Number of service endpoints found: 2
Scaffolding service reference code ...
Error:Unable to generate deps.json, it may have been already generated.  You can specify the "-d" option before the tool name for diagnostic output (for example, "dotnet -d <toolname>": C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.503\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\GenerateDeps\GenerateDeps.proj
Done.
```

Comment: Try to check [Impossible to generate web service client with Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider: Unable to generate deps.json #3143](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/3143)

Comment: I had it too. Updating VS did not help. Starting VS2019 _with_ admin rights did the trick for me. (saw some mention of the MS guys about readonly)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue recently in Visual Studio 2019 (16.8.4) with a `.NET Standard 2.0` class library. I was able to use `svcutil.exe` from the command line to generate code from an existing Webservice (asmx). But with Visual Studio (`Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider`) I got this error.

The funny thing for me was running Visual Studio as an administrator did the trick for me (I never expected that to be honest).

Comment: thanks! starting Visual Studio 2022 as Administrator also solves a similar issue. i had the error `ErrorMSBuild version 17.3.0+92e077650 for .NET` ... `warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" that could not be resolved. [C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2023_Mar_14_11_14_32\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj]` ... `error : A PackageReference to Microsoft.Build.* without ExcludeAssets="runtime" exists in your project`